# How to connect to a Remote database with sonar

Tags: sonarqube

If I have sonar installed on a solaris machine. Is that possible to remote connect to the database in other solaris box? Thanks

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Please go and read the documentation on Sonar's website, everything is clearly explained there (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installation+in+4+steps).